# Can we delete an object passed as by reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

My code is as below

```
 fun(int &a)
 {
    delete &a;
 }

 main()
 {
     int *a = new int(10);
     fun(*a);
 }
```

Can I delete memory assigned in main function and passed as by reference in fun and deleting memory in fun?
Is it the right way?

Comment: This is no `C`....

Comment: Yes its correct... Didn't you tried it ?

Comment: I tried it and it was working. But I never seen deleting object like this so was having dobt.

Comment: It is correct, but if you are in a situation to do this in your code, then you are not in a good position and should look back at what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:
   Yes, you can.
   Do not do it.

References are inmutable, that is, the address (if the compiler implemented the reference as a pointer) is inmutable const. So, if you delete it, the original reference will be pointing to unallocated memory and will crash.

Also, notice that from your code your are passing a reference to the first (and unique) element of the array (if one thinks in pointer as arrays), but fun does not know the size of the array not event that is an array. For example:

```
 fun(int &a)
 {
    delete &a;
 }

 main()
 {
     int a = 42;
     fun(a);
 }
```

It will try to delete the address of a reference. Unexpected behaviour.

Comment: "Also, notice that from your code your are passing a reference to the first element of the array" -- No, the OP is not doing that. That aside, this answer is one sentence unexplained answer, two paragraphs commentary. The commentary is not bad (if edited to be correct), but you might want to explain your answer too.

Answer (score 2):

Do not do this:

I guess this is a Mikey-mouse example but in the real world:

1. For a start the `int` in question may not be created by `new` - Here is a lot of problems
2. Who owns the object in question. Not the function. Where is the contract?

Please decide who owns an object. Also if the "person" creates it via `new` should be responsible to `delete` it.

Check out smart pointers